# What is the distribution of this random variable

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, hypothesis-testing

From an exam question regarding hypothesis testing and the t-distribution

For $X_1,\cdots,X_n\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ what is the distribution of

$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\sigma}
$

I'm struggling to solve this one, if the denominator were $\sigma^2$ then the under a hypothesis $H_0:\mu=0$ I believe that the variable would be distributed $\chi^2(n-1)$ however as it is I am at a loss, am I missing something blatantly obvious?

Comment: I think you've got something weird with the hypothesis test. We'd never test $H_0 : \mu = \bar X$ since we can never reject this as $\bar X$ is the MLE of the likelihood for the mean. Do you maybe mean $H_0 : \mu = 0$ or more generically $H_0 : \mu=\mu_0$ for some fixed $\mu_0$?

Comment: Apologies, I've edited the post to fix my mistake

Comment: Need $\sigma^2$ in denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\sigma} = \sigma \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\sigma^2}.
$$

Working out the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\sigma^2}$:

$$
\sum_i \left(\frac{X_i-\bar{X}}{\sigma}\right)^2 = \sum_i 
\left(\frac{X_i - \mu}{\sigma} - \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2
$$
$$
= \sum_i (Z_i - \bar Z)^2
$$
where the $Z_i$ are iid $\mathcal N(0,1)$.
$$
 \sum_i (Z_i - \bar Z)^2 = \sum_i Z_i^2 - n\bar Z^2 \sim \chi_{n-1}^2
$$
by [Cochran's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem).

This means
$$
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{(X_i-\bar{X})^2}{\sigma} \sim \sigma \cdot \chi^2_{n-1}.
$$
and I think that's the best we can say. There isn't an $n-1$ term because this is the sum of squares, not the variance estimate.

In a Gaussian sample $\sum_i (X_i - \bar X)^2$ is [ancillary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancillary_statistic) to $\mu$ so that's why this result doesn't actually depend on your hypothesis about $\mu$.